# stateless protocol and stateful protocol

Tags: http, networking, network-protocols

How to understand stateless protocol and stateful protocol? HTTP is a stateless protocol and FTP is a stateful protocol. For the web applications requiring a lot of interactions, the underlying protocol should be stateful ones. Is my understanding right?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since you're asking about a Web application, the protocol will always be stateless -- the protocol for the Web is http (or https), and that's all she wrote.

I think what you're thinking of is providing a state mechanism in your Web application itself. The typical approach to this is that you create a unique identifier for the user's session in your Web application (a sessionID of one form or another is the common practice) which is handed back and forth between browser and server. That's typically done in a cookie, though it can be done, with a bit more hassle for you depending on your platform/framework, on the URL as well.

Your server-side code stores stateful information (again, typically called the user's session) however it wants to using the sessionID to look it up. The http traffic simply hands back the sessionID. As long as that identifier is there, each http transaction is completely independent of all others, hence the protocol traffic itself is stateless.

Answer (score 56):

HTTP is a stateless protocol, in other word the server will forget everything related to client/browser state. Although web applications have made it virtually look like stateful.

A stateless protocol can be forced to behave as if it were stateful. This can be accomplished if the server sends the state to the client, and if the client to sends it back again to the server, every time.

There are three ways this may be accomplished in HTTP:

a) One is cookies, in which case the state is sent and returned in HTTP headers.

b) The second is URL extension, in which case the state is sent as part of the URL as request.

c) The third is "hidden form fields", in which the state is sent to the client as part of the response, and returned to the server as part of a form's hidden data

SCALABILITY AND HIGH AVAILABILITY

One of the major reasons why HTTP scales so well is its Statelessness. Stateless protocol eases the replication concerns, as the state itself doesn't need to be stored on the server.

Stateful protocols are logically heavy to implement in Internet reliably. Stateless servers are also easily scalable, while for stateful servers scalablity is problematic. Stateless request can be sent to any node, at any time, while with Stateful this is not a case.

HTTP as Stateless protocol increases availability for stateless web applications, which otherwise would be difficult or impossible to implement. If there is connection lost, there is no state that is lost, simple request resend will resolve the problem. Stateless requests are also cacheable.

[see more here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t149832-is-http-stateful-or-stateless.html)

Comment: "b) The second is URL extension, in which case the state is sent as part of the URL as response.". This is wrong, a URL not is a `response`, but a `request` from the client and can have URL parameters in case of `get` and then evaluated by the server. "c) The third is "hidden form fields", in which the state is sent to the client as part of the response, and returned to the server as part of a form's hidden data" also has to be changed/rewritten.

Answer (score 7):

HTTP is a `stateless protocol`. All the web-based applications are also `stateless`.

When a request is send to the server, a connection is established between client and server. The server receives the request, processes the request and sends back the response and then, the connection will be closed.

If another request will be sent, after that, it will be treated as a new request and a new connection will be established.

In order to make HTTP `stateful`, we use *session management techniques*.
So that, it uses the data coming from previous request while processing present request i.e, it uses the same connection for a series of client server interactions.

The session management techniques are:

1. hidden form field
2. cookie
3. session
4. URL-rewriting

Comment: `request scope`, `session scope` and `application scope` can also be used for session management

Answer (score 7):

```
Anything that forgets whatever it did in past is stateless, such as http
Anything that can keep the history is statefull, such as database
```

Http is a stateless protocol, that's why it forgets the user information.

We make http as statefull protocol using **jsonWebToken(JWT)** i.e. on each request going to server, server will first verify the user using **JWT**.

Comment: nice explaination

Answer (score 2):

Your question is spot on, and yes, it would be great if your web transactions with your bank were done over a stateful connection. Alas, HTTP is stateless due to a quirky bug in FTP and a 12 socket limit in the partial socket table in BSD of 1989. Marcus Ranum explained it all [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o59mQhBiUo4).

So HTTP throws away the state it inherits from TCP and has to recreate state at the application layer in the form of cookies. Crappy internet security is the result.

The [Seif project](http://www.seif.place) proposes to fix all that using "secure JSON over TCP". DNS and certificate authorities are not required. The protocol and seifnode.js are finished and on github with an MIT license.

Answer (score 1):

> HTTP doesn't 'inherit' from TCP, but rather uses it for a transport. HTTP uses TCP for a stateful connection, but then disconnects. Later it will connect again, if needed. So, while you browse through a web site you create many different connections. Each one of those connections is stateful, but the conversation as a whole is not, since you are dropping the connection with every conversation.

[From this link](http://www.itorian.com/2012/09/tcp-is-stateful-protocol-and-http-is.html)

Answer (score 0):

Basically yes, but you have no choice but use HTTP which is where websites are served in. So you have to deal with compromises to make HTTP stateful, aka session management. Possibilities are basically passing on a session id through each call in the URL so you know when you're talking to someone you've talked about before, or via cookies, which achieve the same goal without cluttering the url. However, most modern web development languages take care of that for you; if you google for the language of your choice + "session management" you should get some ideas of how it's done.