# What if HTTP protocol is stateful?

Tags: http, protocols

I know that HTTP is a stateless protocol. But there is no proper explanation for statelessness of HTTP protocol. Why HTTP protocol is stateless? What happens when HTTP Protocol is stateful ?

Comment: What happens if a mouse flies? This is no "what happens" question. HTTP isn't stateful. Period. It's how the protocol is designed.

Comment: Can go through the same on this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836881/stateless-protocol-and-stateful-protocol

Answer (score 5):

> *There is no proper explanation for statelessness of HTTP protocol.*

You probably have missed the [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230), one of the documents that define the HTTP protocol. See some quotes below:

> HTTP is a stateless request/response protocol that operates by
> exchanging messages across a reliable transport- or
> session-layer "connection". [...]

> HTTP is defined as a stateless protocol, meaning that each request
> message can be understood in isolation.  Many implementations depend
> on HTTP's stateless design in order to reuse proxied connections or
> dynamically load balance requests across multiple servers. [...]

---

> *What happens when HTTP Protocol is stateful?*

It doesn't happen: *HTTP is not stateful and won't be*.

The [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) defines some mechanisms for state management in HTTP, such as cookies, but it doesn't make HTTP stateful.

As described in the [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230), HTTP/1.1 supports *"persistent connections"*, allowing multiple requests and responses to be carried over a single connection, but it also doesn't make HTTP a stateful protocol in any way.

If you need a stateful protocol, you may look at WebSockets, defined in the [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455). It can *coexist* with HTTP and can deployed in the HTTP infrastructure.